# JavaFX Node will not grow in height despite constraints when buried within several panes

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I've been struggling with this issue for a couple hours and managed to reproduce the problem with the sample below. The actual program changes what is set in `main.add(node, 0, 1)` as the content based on what button is pressed in `menu`. I tried several different things such as AnchorPanes, changing setMaxHeight, and setVgrow for many different nodes in the each pane but have not been very successful. How would I make the ListView in the example fill the rest of the window height where it is located?

```
public class Main extends Application {

    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        // I've tried with this as a VBox, no effect.
        GridPane main = new GridPane();
        main.setGridLinesVisible(true);
        main.setHgap(5);
        main.setVgap(10);

        // Meant to change what content is displayed in the actual program.
        HBox menu = new HBox();
        menu.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        menu.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        main.add(menu, 0, 0);
        GridPane.setHgrow(menu, Priority.ALWAYS);
        menu.getChildren().addAll(new Button("Button 1"), new Button("Button 2"), new Button("Button 3"), new Label("Hello world!"));

        // Changes often.
        GridPane content = new GridPane();
        main.add(content, 0, 1);

        // Options for the displayed content, changes the StackPane displayed below in my actual program.
        HBox submenu = new HBox();
        submenu.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        submenu.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        content.add(submenu, 0, 0);
        GridPane.setHgrow(submenu, Priority.ALWAYS);
        submenu.getChildren().addAll(new Button("Button A"), new Button("Button B"), new Button("Button C"), new Label("Hello world!"));

        // This is a custom class extended by StackPane in my actual program. Is often over overlayed with another transparent StackPane (not relevant to the problem).
        StackPane subcontent = new StackPane();
        subcontent.setMaxHeight(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        subcontent.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        content.add(subcontent, 0, 1);

        // This was meant to be a TabPane in my actual program but this has the same outcome that won't fill the rest of the window height.
        ListView<String> list = new ListView<>();
        list.setMaxHeight(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        list.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        ObservableList<String> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        list.setItems(items);

        subcontent.getChildren().add(list);

        for(int i=0; i<100; i++) {
            items.add("# "+i);
        }

        Scene scene = new Scene(main, 900, 550);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need both

```
GridPane.setVgrow(content, Priority.ALWAYS);
```

and

```
GridPane.setVgrow(subcontent, Priority.ALWAYS);
```

The grid panes are going to size things to their preferred heights with the default `vgrow`: the preferred height of `content` is determined by the preferred height(s) of its child nodes, and the preferred height of a `ListView` is a fixed (arbitrary) size (I believe 400 pixels). So if you don't instruct `subcontent` to grow, it will by the preferred size of the list view, and forcing `content` to grow will just add extra (blank) space to `content`: if you don't force `content` to grow, it will take its preferred size, which is the preferred size of `subcontent` plus the preferred size of `submenu`.

Setting the max height doesn't do anything in this example, as you just need to allow the various nodes to grow beyond their preferred size:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        // I've tried with this as a VBox, no effect.
        GridPane main = new GridPane();
        main.setGridLinesVisible(true);
        main.setHgap(5);
        main.setVgap(10);

        // Meant to change what content is displayed in the actual program.
        HBox menu = new HBox();
//        menu.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        menu.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        main.add(menu, 0, 0);
        GridPane.setHgrow(menu, Priority.ALWAYS);
        menu.getChildren().addAll(new Button("Button 1"), new Button("Button 2"), new Button("Button 3"), new Label("Hello world!"));

        // Changes often.
        GridPane content = new GridPane();
        main.add(content, 0, 1);

        // Options for the displayed content, changes the StackPane displayed below in my actual program.
        HBox submenu = new HBox();
//        submenu.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        submenu.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        content.add(submenu, 0, 0);
        GridPane.setHgrow(submenu, Priority.ALWAYS);
        submenu.getChildren().addAll(new Button("Button A"), new Button("Button B"), new Button("Button C"), new Label("Hello world!"));

        // This is a custom class extended by StackPane in my actual program. Is often over overlayed with another transparent StackPane (not relevant to the problem).
        StackPane subcontent = new StackPane();
//        subcontent.setMaxHeight(Double.MAX_VALUE);
//        subcontent.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        content.add(subcontent, 0, 1);


        // This was meant to be a TabPane in my actual program but this has the same outcome that won't fill the rest of the window height.
        ListView<String> list = new ListView<>();
//        list.setMaxHeight(Double.MAX_VALUE);
//        list.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        ObservableList<String> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        list.setItems(items);

        subcontent.getChildren().add(list);

        for(int i=0; i<100; i++) {
            items.add("# "+i);
        }

        GridPane.setVgrow(content, Priority.ALWAYS);
        GridPane.setVgrow(subcontent, Priority.ALWAYS);


        Scene scene = new Scene(main, 900, 550);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Your explanation helped make sense of what was going on.